# Github Travis CI with pytest and package data - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, github, pytest, travis-ci

I've got a repo on GitHub, for which I wanted to implement Travis CI with `pytest` for basic testing. Currently the Travis CI build fails when loading data tables within a module, raising a `FileNotFoundError`.
To make it short, here is the imho most important information on the build:

- directory of the data tables is included in `MANIFEST.in` with `include mypkg/data_tables/*` (see below for a detailed structure)
- `setuptools.setup` method has the `include_package_data=True` parameter
- additionally `packages=setuptools.find_packages()` is provided
- **Travis CI** installs the package with `install: pip install -e .`
- Travis CI pytest is invoked with `script: pytest --import-mode=importlib`
- during testing the first tests succeed. But when it comes to loading the data tables, pytest raises the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/travis/build/myname/mypkg/mypkg/data_tables\\my_data.csv'`

Interestingly the slashes before the file name are back-slashes, while the other are not, even though the final path is constructed with `os.path.abspath()`.

---

### Detailed description

Unluckily the repo is private and I'm not allowed to share it. Thus I'll try to describe the GitHub package layout as detailed as possible. So let's say my repo is built with a structure like this (general layout taken from [this example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code)):

```
setup.py
MANIFEST.in
mypkg/
    some_data_tables/
        my_data.csv
        my_other_data.pkl
    __init__.py
    view.py
tests/
    test_view.py
```

My minimum `MANIFEST.in` looks like this:

```
include mypkg/data_tables/*
```

With the `setup.py` fully reduced to a minimum working example like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
    name='Mypkg',
    version='123.456',
    description='some_text',
    python_requires='>=3.7.7',
    packages=find_packages(  # <---- this should be sufficient, right?
        exclude=["tests", "*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*"]),
    include_package_data=True,  # <---- also this should work
)
```

And the `.travis.yml` file (omitting `- pip install -r requirements.txt` etc.):

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.7.7"
dist: xenial

install:
  - pip install -e .

script:
    - pytest --import-mode=importlib
```

---

**Checking the content of the `.egg` or `tar.gz` files, the data tables are included.** So I have no idea, where the files are "getting lost".
Any idea how to solve this error?

If providing more information could help, f.i. on the class initialized in `test_view`, please tell me.

Comment: These backslashes look suspicious - they must come from somewhere, as they will not be created by any`os.path` functions under Linux. The data will not be found with the backslashes in the path.

Comment: Yeah, strange... I create the path with `os.path.abspath(path_to_datatables + r'\my_data.csv')`. On my machine it works and all parts of the path have double-backslashes. On travis this strangely fails. No idea why...

Comment: Well, there you have it - you add the backslash yourself. Use `os.path.join` instead. Maybe you are under Windows?

Comment: Yep. And it seems like `os.path.abspath` keeps the backslash under Linux while under Windows the path is converted... Damn, that's nasty... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, yes - under Linux the backslash is just a character in the path, not a path delimiter, so there is no reason to convert it. Never use the literal path delimiters in code that shall run on both Windows and Unix.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! This could be a useful addition to `os` to warn about backslashes...